# Regex for month with optional leading 0

Tags: regex

I am trying to match various months, that may be in the form of:

```
01
1
12
13
09
```

All of the above inputs are valid except for `13`.

The current regex I have for this is:

```
0?(?#optional leading 0, for example 04)
\d(?#followed by any number, 01, 2, 09, etc.)
|(?#or 10,11,12)
1[012]
```

What's wrong with the above regex? Here's an example link: https://regex101.com/r/cujCmD/1

Comment: Do you need to use a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would phrase the regex as:

```
^(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])$
```

### Demo

The parentheses and anchors are needed to ensure that the alternation chosen gets applied to the entire number input.

Comment: thanks. I've noticed it works fine when enclosing it in parentheses but not when I don't have them. Why is that? I thought the parenths were for capturing the group, why's it needed here?